# Javascript, async, lock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I know async is not parallel but I bumped into a quite funny situation now.

```
async function magic(){
  /* some processing here */
  await async () => await prompt_for_user(); // 1st prompt
  await async () => await prompt_for_user(); // 2nd prompt
}

magic(); // first
magic(); // second
magic(); // third
```

From the program above, we could easily predicts that all prompts pops up together at the same time. I tried to solve it with a queue with the following implementation:

```
 const Queue = () => {
  let promise;
  return async (f) => {
    while(promise) await promise;
    promise = f();
    const res = await promises;
    promise = undefined;
    return res;
  };
};


const queue = Queue();
async function magic(){
  /* some processing here */
  await queue(async () => await prompt_for_user()); // 1st prompt
  await queue(async () => await prompt_for_user()); // 2nd prompt
}

magic(); // first
magic(); // second
magic(); // third
```

This stops the prompt from popping up all at a time. But there is a second problem:

So when the first `magic()` is called. A prompt `first.1` is shown to the user. The program continues and the second `magic()` is called. Another prompt `second.1` is awaiting for the first prompt to finish before showing up. Then the program continues, the third `magic()` is called and `third.1` again awaits for `first.1` to finish. When `first.1` finishes, meaning the user have typed the value, `second.1` will pop up first but I wish `first.2` to pop up first.

I know one obvious solution would be await the magic one by one. But this would lose the asynchronous advantages that js gives us. If the processing is heavy in magic before prompting, it will take some time before prompting.

Idea?

Comment: This is a bit of an XY problem where you've shown us your attempted solution without showing us the REAL problem.  We could probably help you better if you showed us the actual problem you're trying to solve.  I would guess that a recursive solution where you call a function, prompt for input, then when you receive that async input, you process it and decide what to do next where one of the options is prompt for more input and another option is to call the host function again to continue the chain of processing.  But, without seeing your real problem, we can't really advise the best solution.

Comment: As it stands now, your queue looks overly complicated for the likely problem if we could see the real issue to be solved.  FYI, if you didn't know what an XY problem is, it is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, I don't really see how this works. When you have nested `await`s those will always come after the other async calls (just purely because that's the order the compiler sees them) i.e. first async starts and run loop starts to process other sync code, which will fire the other prompts. You're at the mercy of the run loop / internal prioritisation here.

Comment: I have edited the code to show a better picture.

Comment: Your question is STILL unclear.  You can't have your cake and eat it too.  You can't process all your files in parallel and have random user interactions popup and know which file they belong to.  Pick one or the other.  And, this whole Queue thing seems like nothing but a complication.  Of course, if we understood what the actual problem is you're trying to solve with actual code for real async operations, we could likely show you a very elegant way to solve your issue.

Comment: If you want to process a bunch of things in parallel (which you seem to be saying you want to do) and know when they are all done, you will need to accumulate an array of promises and use `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done.  Each individual operation can be it's own separate promise chain that uses await inside its chain.  No need for the Queue that I see.

Comment: honestly, the code shown is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Except that it does work because it's not an appropriate architecture.  You can't run multiple independent operations in parallel, but expect the unknown in advance number of input requests to pop up serially in order.  That's an architectural conflict.  There is no solution to that problem.  When operation N wants to prompt for input, the ONLY way it can make sure it is asking for input in order is it will have to KNOW that all of the operations before it are done with requesting input and the only way it appears to know that is if they are actually done which means serializing most of work.

Comment: The only questions I  have are: 1. does every item need user input? 2. does the user input come before or after some async processing?

Comment: 1. some item does have user, but not all.
2. there are async processing both before and after

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for you comment. You inspired me! Maybe we could use semaphore!

Comment: There are no such things as semaphores in Javascript.  Do you realize that `await` only blocks execution within the `async` function itself.  Other Javascript and other functions outside continue to run.  So `await` only helps you serialize things within the function.  It does not coordinate or block with things outside that function.

Comment: I do know. But we could borrow the concept of it.

Comment: Updated the answer to have someAsyncBefore and someAsyncAfter. Not all values require user input but if they do it'll ask one after the other. Another update I added is to handle failed results (not let it reject because you'll loose all resolved values).

Comment: @jfriend00 Have a look at my semaphore inspired implementation! :D Now who says we can't implement semaphore!

Comment: OK, I implemented a non-spinning semaphore that chains promises to serialize the input prompts.  Answer posted below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I had trouble understanding your overall objective until you posted your semaphore answer, I'll define the question I'm attempting to answer as this.

1. You want to run a series of asynchronous operations with as much parallelism as possible (serialized the least amount necessary).
2. One or more operations may need to prompt the user for info.
3. All user prompts must be in precise serial order for how the code is ordered.  So, the first function that is called and prompts must prompt first.
4. If that same function prompts more than once, all of its prompts must come before any others.
5. So basically, all the prompts must be serialized, but any other async stuff that comes before or after the prompts can run in parallel.
6. The best code will not "spin" or "poll" a flag, but will preserve CPU cycles for other operations by getting notified when something that is waiting is ready to run (one big principle behind promises).

Here's a scheme, modeled after the one you posted, but it uses a chain of promises (no spinning or polling a flag) to force serialization of the `prompt()` calls (anything between `.start()` and `.end()` calls while allowing all other operations to run in parallel.  This should be a lot more efficient with CPU usage.

```js
let Semaphore = (function() {
    // private data shared among all instances
    let sharedPromise = Promise.resolve();
    
    return class Sempaphore {
        constructor() {
            let priorP = sharedPromise;
            let resolver;
            
            // create our promise (to be resolved later)
            let newP = new Promise(resolve => {
                resolver = resolve;
            });
            
            // chain our position onto the sharedPromise to force serialization
            // of semaphores based on when the constructor is called
            sharedPromise = sharedPromise.then(() => {
                return newP;
            });
            
            // allow caller to wait on prior promise for its turn in the chain
            this.start = function() {
                return priorP;
            }
            
            // finish our promise to enable next caller in the chain to get notified
            this.end = function() {
                resolver();
            }
        }
    }
})();

// use random times to test our async better
function prompt(tag, n) {
  log(tag, 'input please: ', n);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 500);
  });
};

function log(...args) {
    if (!log.start) {
        log.start = Date.now();
    }
    let diff = ((Date.now() - log.start) / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log(diff + ": ", ...args);
}

function randomDelay(low = 500, high = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low)) + low);
  });
}

async function magic1(tag){
  // declare semaphore before any async code to reserve your order for semaphored code below
  let s = new Semaphore();

  // whatever sync or async code you want here
  log(tag, 'do some busy async work 1a');
  await randomDelay(800, 1200);
  log(tag, 'do some busy work 1b');

  // start of our serialized critical section
  await s.start();
  await prompt(tag, 1);
  await prompt(tag, 2);
  s.end();
  // end of our serialized critical section

  // whatever sync or async code you want here
  log(tag, 'do more busy work 1c');
  await randomDelay();
}

async function magic2(tag){
  let s = new Semaphore();
  log(tag, 'do some busy async work 2a');
  // this delay purposely causes magic2 async delay to be shorter 
  // than magic1 for testing purposes
  await randomDelay(100, 750);
  log(tag, 'do some busy work 2b');
  await s.start();
  await prompt(tag, 3);
  await prompt(tag, 4);
  s.end();
  log(tag, 'do more busy work 2c');
  await randomDelay();
}

Promise.all([
    magic1("magic1a"),
    magic1("magic1b"),
    magic2("magic2a"),
    magic2("magic2b")
]).then(() => {
    log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    log("err: ", err);
});
```

And here's some sample output (output will vary slightly because of random async delays done for testing purposes).  But, input calls will always be in exactly the same order:

```
0.000:  magic1a do some busy async work 1a
0.003:  magic1b do some busy async work 1a
0.004:  magic2a do some busy async work 2a
0.004:  magic2b do some busy async work 2a
0.600:  magic2b do some busy work 2b
0.721:  magic2a do some busy work 2b
0.829:  magic1b do some busy work 1b
1.060:  magic1a do some busy work 1b
1.061:  magic1a input please:  1
2.179:  magic1a input please:  2
2.860:  magic1a do more busy work 1c
2.862:  magic1b input please:  1
3.738:  magic1b input please:  2
4.500:  magic1b do more busy work 1c
4.502:  magic2a input please:  3
5.845:  magic2a input please:  4
6.497:  magic2a do more busy work 2c
6.498:  magic2b input please:  3
7.516:  magic2b input please:  4
8.136:  magic2b do more busy work 2c
9.097:  all done
```

Some explanation:

1. Where you put `let s = new Sempaphore();` in the code is where you this function to "put itself in line" for serialization so something that hasn't already put itself in line have it's critical section be forced to come after this function's critical section.  This "reserves" a spot in line, but doesn't actually start a critical section yet.  This is important if you have other indeterminate async code that runs before the critical section.  You need to reserve your place in line before now before your async code, but not actual wait for the place in line until right before the critical section.
2. Where you put `await s.start();` in the function is where you want it to actually wait for your spot in line for a critical section.
3. Where you put `s.end()` is the end of your critical section (allowing other critical sections to now also run when its their turn).
4. This demo shows async code running both before and after the critical sections of prompts.  That code can run in parallel with other things.
5. Non-input related async operations can be interleaved between input prompts even in the same critical section (by design).  Only input prompts are forced to be serialized.

Comment: This is very clear and I love it. This doesn't seem to be something that's rare, do you know any library providing the similar kind of functionality?

Comment: @JasonYu - I'm not aware of any library to do this.  Most people who need to serialize part of an operation decide to just serialize the whole operation because it is a lot more complicated to serialize only part of it than to just serialize the whole thing.

Comment: Serialising the whole thing just isn't effective enough don't you think?

Comment: @JasonYu - Serializing the whole thing is not as "optimized" as it could be, but an order of magnitude simpler to implement and avoid bugs in.  It's a tradeoff.

Comment: So should I be reading files synchronously? That seems to be a very non js.

Comment: @JasonYu - Not sure what you mean by that.  There are lots of tradeoffs between speed of producing code, complexity, performance of code, maintainability, reliability, etc...  Good developers choose the right balance for the situation.  The fastest solution that is really complex is not necessarily always the right choice, nor is an oversimplified solution that's really slow.  Must select appropriate balance for the situation.

Comment: I don't think this method is too much of an overkill tho. Just need a bit of refractor I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161199/discussion-between-jason-yu-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score -2):

So after testing for a while, finally I got an answer! Inspired by the concept of semaphore, I have created the following:

```
const Semaphore = (n) => ({
  n,
  async down(){
    while(this.n <= 0) await this.wait();
    this.n--;
  },
  up(){
    this.n++;
  },
  async wait(){
    if(this.n <= 0) return await new Promise((res, req) => {
      setImmediate(async () => res(await this.wait()))
    });
    return;
  },
});

const prompt = (n) => {
  console.log('input please: ' + n);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), 3000)
  });
};

const semaphore = Semaphore(1);

async function magic1(){
  console.log('do some busy work 1');
  await semaphore.down();
  await prompt(1);
  await prompt(2);
  semaphore.up();
}

async function magic2(){
  console.log('do some busy work 2');
  await semaphore.down();
  await prompt(3);
  await prompt(4);
  semaphore.up();
}

magic1();
magic1();
magic2();
magic2();
```

Result:

```
do some busy work 1
do some busy work 1
do some busy work 2
do some busy work 2
input please: 1
input please: 2
input please: 1
input please: 2
input please: 3
input please: 4
input please: 3
input please: 4
```

This semaphore essentially busy waits if `n == 0`. Although I call it busy wait, it actually doesn't because `setImmediate` will allow other functions in the event loop to execute! This implementation is the best and elegant working solution that I have come to so far.

Sometimes, it will say [1,2] [3,4] [1,2] [3,4]. But that's ok! It's asynchronous!

Comment: Pretty odd implementation.  If you want to serialize things, I don't understand why you don't just chain promises rather than implement a busy wait loop?  This is horrible for CPU usage because you're spinning waiting for a flag to change.  Promises provide a notification system for events of interest.  You should be using that rather than spin polling a flag.